# Restrict Custom Post Type to One Item

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

I'm looking to build a plugin that stores settings for a companion app my Wordpress site works with. I've gotten to the point where I have a custom post type `mobile_settings` that stores labels and colors unique to the companion app.

I've gotten to the point where I have my new post type and it's meta values stored, as well as created a new admin page. Here's what I can't figure out to do:

1. On the admin page, navigate the user to the "New Item" view if no `mobile_settings` have been created.
2. If a single `mobile_settings` record has been created, navigate the user to it's edit view.

Once I have those, I know how to hide the custom post type from the UI, so the user will think it's a straight "options" page instead of a custom post type.

We are strictly building this from scratch in order to maintain a database structure that works for our needs. It's actually not as hard as I thought it would be =)

Any tips would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I guess some code would be appreciated too, huh?

```
add_menu_page(
    'Mobile Settings',
    'Mobile Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'mobile-settings.php',
    function () {
      $mobile_settings = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'mobile_settings', 'posts_per_page' => 1));
      if (count($mobile_settings) > 0) {
        wp_redirect(get_edit_post_link($mobile_settings[0]->ID) . '&noheader=true');
        exit;
      }
    },
    'dashicons-smartphone',
    5
  );
```

Comment: Have you considered using the wp_options table and just building an options page, instead of a whole CPT? It seems like that would be easier to tailor to your needs.

Comment: I haven't -- could you point me to a tutorial? Also, would it be extensible enough to store arrays?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WebElaine -- I'm converting my custom post type into a Settings page. Can you tell I'm new to this? =)